# How do I fix intermittent Flask Path Constructor 404?

Tags: python, flask

The flask dev server is appending subcategory urls causing 404 errors.

Here is my url structure...

```
/services
/services/marketing/inbound
/services/marketing/outbound
```

My expectation is that if I navigate in this order they all resolve. However, /service urls is being appending by /service like this....

```
GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
GET /about HTTP/1.1" 200
GET /faq HTTP/1.1" 200
GET /contact HTTP/1.1" 200
GET /services/marketing HTTP/1.1" 200
GET /services/services/marketing/inbound HTTP/1.1" 404
GET /services/services/marketing/outbound HTTP/1.1" 404
```

VIEW

```
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def page(path):
    t = Tree(path)
    pg = t.get_page()  # return Page model object
    bc = t.build_path()  # returns bread-crumbs list ['/', 'services']
    mn = t.get_children() # returns sub-menu list ['inbound', 'out-bound']
    return render_template('page.html', pg=pg, bc=bc, mn=mn)
```

TEMPLATE

```
<a href="services/medical-billing-quality-control">Billing Quality Control</a>
```

I've also tried this, but it also results in a URL build error.

```
<a href="{{ url_for('marketing', path=services) }}">Billing Quality Control</a>
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: ('medical-collections',
         {'path': 'services'}, None)
```

Comment: you mean `<a href="{{ url_for('marketing', path=services) }}">`right? with double quotes and matched parenthesis

Comment: correct. I copied and pasted it wrong.  Still not working.

Comment: In your URL `href="services/etc"` should be `href="/services/etc"` (note the leading slash).  Otherwise, the HREF is interpreted as a resource path *relative to the current path*, which is not what you want.  The `BuildError` when you use `url_for` needs more context before we can help you with it.

Comment: Do you have an endpoint named `marketing`? Or is `page` the only one?

Comment: @SeanVieira, yes.  Absolutely correct.  I've added a slash to the template and removed the slash from the database servicing the urls.  Works great now. Please post the answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your URL `href="services/etc"` should be `href="/services/etc"` (note the leading slash). Otherwise, the `href` is interpreted as a resource path *relative to the current path*, which is not what you want.